# Can not send back UDP to internal PC behide NAT

Tags: node.js, udp, nat

I setup two PC,
one is client in local network behide NAT,
another is server on public network.

The test steps are --
1) client listen udp on port 33333
2) server listen udp on port 22222
1) client send udp to server 
2) server received the data and send back

When I test the code on my test network, it's OK.

If put the server on real internet, server can get the message from client,
client can not get response from server.
What's wrong?

Here's testing code with nodejs.

server
    var dgram = require('dgram');

```
var socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
socket.on('message', function (message, remote) {
        console.log('client ip:' + remote.address + ', port:' + remote.port +', message:' + message);
        //send response to client
        var message = new Buffer("hello, client!");
        socket.send(message, 0, message.length, remote.port, remote.address);
});

//listening port
socket.bind(22222);
```

client
    var dgram = require('dgram');

```
var socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

socket.on('message', function (message, remote) {
        //display message from server
        console.log('server ip:' + remote.address + ', port:' + remote.port +', message:' + message);
});

//listening port
socket.bind(33333);

//send message to server
function send(server){
        var message = new Buffer("hello, server!");
        socket.send(message, 0, message.length, 22222, server, function(){
                //send again after 1 seconds
                setTimeout(function(){
                        send(server);
                }, 1000);
        });
};

//suppose that server address is public.server.com
send("public.server.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

NATed computers cannot be reached from outside and this is particularly painful for peer-to-peer or friend-to-friend software. Basically because your PC has not a public IP address but you NAT device has. So, the NAT is visible, your PC isn't.

The server gets the package from the NAT device and send the response to it. Yes, the NAT receives the response and it has to relay it to your PC, that's the trick. To do so you have to configure a port forwarding in the NAT.

The NAT has a table like the following:

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------+ 
| NAT PORT | INTERNAL IP ADDRESS | INTERNAL PORT | 
+----------+---------------------+---------------+
|   33333  | 198.162.0.3 (pc ip) |       33333   |
```

It can be read as: when NAT receives a package in its port #33333 it has to redirected to the internal IP 198.162.0.3 (your PC IP address) and port# 33333.

If your PC uses a fixed IP, you can do this mapping by hand in your NAT. However, if you use a DHCP server, your PC's IP can change after each reboot so you need to do this mapping by software in you project. Most of the NATs support Universal Plug & Play, Port Mapping Protocol or Port Control Protocol to achieve this mapping and you can do it with nodejs given that all you need are the appropiated HTTP request to the NAT.

Yes, you can do it by yourself but it is not so easy. In fact, the discovery process requires you broadcast udp messages in the LAN in specific port. I strongly recommend you to use a third-party component to do it.

I hope this helps you.